# Text Validation Error in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The code is not working the way I want it to.
I wrote this code to display an alert if either login or password field is not filled. But if I fill the login  info and skip password, it doesn't show alert message as planned. Any help will be appreciated.

```js
function check() {
  var x = document.forms['myform']['lid'].value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("Please Enter the Login-Id")
    y = document.forms['myform']['pass'].value;
    if (y == "") {
      alert("The password field can't be blank")
    }
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1> Welcome to X-mail.com </h1><br><br><br>
  <form name='myform'>
    Login-Id<input type="text" name='lid'> </input><br><br> Password
    <input type='password' name='pass'> </input><br><br><br>
    <button onclick="check()"> Login</button>
  </form>
  Don't have an account?
  <a href="signup.html"> Sign-Up </a>
</center>
```

Comment: The code in `if (x==""){` won't be executed when the login field has a value. So `if(y=="")` won't get executed when the login has a value. Maybe add an `or` or an `else`?

Comment: Your function should execute on the form submit rather than the button click. That way if the user submits in a different way, like hitting Enter, your code still runs:    `<form name='myform' onsubmit="check">`

Comment: Also, to prevent submission, you should call `event.preventDefault()` if the input is invalid. See [Form Validation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation).

Answer (score 0):

You just have your two checks nested in one another. They need to be separate like this:

```
function check() {
    var x = document.forms['myform']['lid'].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Please Enter the Login-Id")

    }
    y = document.forms['myform']['pass'].value;
    if (y == "") {
        alert("The password field can't be blank")
    }

}
```

Ideally, you want to check if both are missing and only show a single alert but I will leave that up to you to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Your check function logic seems to be nested and that's the issue. The correct logic needs to be

```
function check() {
            var x = document.forms['myform']['lid'].value;
            if (x == "") {
                alert("Please Enter the Login-Id")   
            }
            y = document.forms['myform']['pass'].value;
            if (y == "") {
                alert("The password field can't be blank")
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closed bracket after your first `if` statement.

```
if (x==""){
alert("Please Enter the Login-Id")
} // make sure you close your bracket here
y=document.forms['myform']['pass'].value;
... rest of your code ...
```

If you do that and have two `if`s, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the validation for the `pass` field will only occur if the `lid` field is equal to `""`. Move the validation for the `pass` field outside of the validation for the login-id field.

```js
function check() {
  var x = document.forms['myform']['lid'].value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("Please Enter the Login-Id")
  }
  y = document.forms['myform']['pass'].value;
    if (y == "") {
      alert("The password field can't be blank")
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1> Welcome to X-mail.com </h1><br><br><br>
  <form name='myform'>
    Login-Id<input type="text" name='lid'> </input><br><br> Password
    <input type='password' name='pass'> </input><br><br><br>
    <button onclick="check()"> Login</button>
  </form>
  Don't have an account?
  <a href="signup.html"> Sign-Up </a>
</center>
```

Additionally you may want to pass in the `event` Object into the function to prevent the default action (submitting the form) with `event.preventDefault()` if the validation does not pass.

```js
function check(e) {
  var x = document.forms['myform']['lid'].value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("Please Enter the Login-Id");
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  y = document.forms['myform']['pass'].value;
    if (y == "") {
      alert("The password field can't be blank");
      e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1> Welcome to X-mail.com </h1><br><br><br>
  <form name='myform'>
    Login-Id<input type="text" name='lid'> </input><br><br> Password
    <input type='password' name='pass'> </input><br><br><br>
    <button onclick="check(event)"> Login</button>
  </form>
  Don't have an account?
  <a href="signup.html"> Sign-Up </a>
</center>
```